# MySQL workbench failing to download

Tags: mysql, visual-studio, download, mysql-workbench, workbench

I have a Mac and use parallels to access Windows 11. I am trying to download MySQL, and everything successfully downloaded except for the Workbench. It fails to install every time with the error, "The processor is not adequate for running MySQL Workbench 8.0 CE."

I have tried googling and searching through forums and videos, and cannot find this exact error, and have tried using solutions from similar workbench issues.

I have tried uninstalling the program, and reinstalling, as well as restarting Windows and the computer as a whole. I have downloaded Visual Code 2022, 2019, and 2017 in hopes that one of these would work, but none did. I also added the development C++ add on to Visual Code like some people suggested, and that did not help. I also have downloaded the 2017 Visual C++ Redistributable for Visual Studio 2017 (version 15.9) and tried to "repair" it. Still did not work, still get the same error. Also, I have already downloaded NET framework 4.5, so that is not the problem either.

I don't know where else to look, or what other resources to try and was wondering if anyone had any ideas or knows to how to solve this issue. Thank you for any help!

Answer (score 5):

Windows on ARM emulation isn't good enough to trick the MySQL Workbench installer into thinking that it's running on an Intel CPU, so the installation fails.

Fortunately, this is fixable with some degree of effort - you have to patch the MSI file. There's likely other ways to do the patch, but here's how I did it using Orca:

- Install the Visual Studio 2022 ARM preview and include the tools needed for C++ development. This will get the Windows SDK installed.
- Run the Orca installer that's bundled with the Windows SDK (it will be put somewhere like "C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\bin\WINDOWS SDK VERSION\x86\Orca-x86_en-us.msi")
- Download the MySQL Workbench .msi installer from https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/workbench/. Do *not* use the MySQL Installer that handles everything - you want the dedicated installer that handles just Workbench.
- Right click the downloaded .msi, choose "Show More Options" and then "Edit with Orca"
- Open the "LaunchCondition" table in the left hand list.
- In the right hand side, there will be a row saying "Intel >= 5". Right click it and select "Drop Row" to remove the CPU check.
- File > Save As and save your modified .MSI file.

You can now run the modified .MSI file and it'll install Workbench just fine on your Windows 11 on ARM environment. It works great in Parallels on my M2 MacBook Air!

Comment: deserve more credit for this answer. Thank you.

Comment: I followed these steps and then would get an error when attempting to run the modified msi, "internal error 2356 product.cab".


To resolve this issue, I had to verify that the following setting was enabled within Orca before saving the modified msi: Tools > Options > Database > Copy Embedded Streams during 'Save As'.

Answer (score 2):

your Mac silicon is M1?
M1 not support, intel is ok

Comment: ah yes!! this must be it! mine is M1. Thank you so much, I appreciate your help!!

Comment: Of note .. Workbench works inside of Windows, Linux and Apple ..so you could still use it most likely in your native os.

Answer (score 0):

Based on answer posted here before, I just edit the .msi installation file for Workbench and founf in the keywords "Intel >= 5", then I replaced the ">=" for "<=" and voila!. The installation run fine and the program works fine, except some details like the "run/Stop" feature and the "Server Status", bat Query editor works fine.