# MySQL Workbench installer gives Internal Error 2354, product.cab on Macbook Air M1. How do I fix this?

Tags: mysql-workbench, windows-11

I'm running Windows 11 on a MacBook Air M1 through UTM, and I have a little problem trying to install MySQL Workbench. I've modified the installer through Orca to run it on ARM processors, but now it gives this error during the installation: Internal Error 2354, product cab.

I've tried modifying the row that controls the processor instead of deleting it, but it still gives me the same error during installation. I followed the steps written in another thread that I'll leave here: [MySQL workbench failing to download](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71461848/mysql-workbench-failing-to-download)

I don't know if it could be a problem related to UTM, since other people was able to run it properly on Parallels Desktop. I haven't found anything on Google, forums, or whatever. I hope someone is able to help me.

Comment: This might be the only time I make a suggestion like this, but, you know that MySQL Workbench works natively in Mac OS as well, so the Windows 11 version is not required, but I get wanting to multi-os with an M chip.

Comment: Note the thing you linked has this answer as to WHY you are having this problem and perhaps why my comment above this one might be the solution.
"Windows on ARM emulation isn't good enough to trick the MySQL Workbench installer into thinking that it's running on an Intel CPU, so the installation fails."

Comment: I'm very curious to what you decide to do here, as the main reason to use an M1 chip is the multiple simultanious operating systems option , but if you prefer using Windows, why even add the mac os part of this and just buy a much cheaper and much faster pc instead?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of doing save as, just save the installer as is and run the original installer you downloaded after the orca edit and then the installation will go through.